# Web API 2 response design issue

Tags: c#, reflection, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having some design problems (I think) and are looking for advice/alternative solutions. I have some base classes and one interface.

```
public interface IBuildLinks
{
    void BuildLinks(Uri root);
}

public abstract class AbstractModel : IBuildLinks
{
    public void BuildLinks(Uri root)
    {
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractCollectionModel<T> where T : AbstractModel, IBuildLinks
{
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }

    public void BuildLinks(Uri root)
    {
    }
}
```

And some implementations of these classes:

```
public class AssortmentModel : AbstractModel
{
}

public class AssortmentCollectionModel : AbstractCollectionModel<AssortmentModel>
{
}
```

I have a filter that should call `BuildLinks` if the response is a type that implements `IBuildLinks`

```
public class BuildModelLinksFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        var content = context.Response.Content as ObjectContent;
        if (content == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var type = content.ObjectType;

        if (type.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IBuildLinks)))
        {
            var value = (IBuildLinks)content.Value;
            var root = context.Request.GetRootUrl();

            value.BuildLinks(new Uri(root));
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work since derived types like `AssortmentCollectionModel` is not recognized as implementing `IBuildLinks`

If I slap the `IBuildLinks` interface on every derived class it does work. It feels like there is a better way to do this so I'm looking for suggestions on how to improve the code. Perhaps I could do this fundamentally different in some way?

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code should work fine but it looks like you have the call to `IsAssignableFrom` reversed. The method tests whether the argument can be assigned to a variable of that type, so it should read:

```
if (typeof(IBuildLinks).IsAssignableFrom(type))
```

You mentioned that it did work when you added the `IBuildLinks` interface to the derived classes but I can't see how this would be the case unless you also changed the return type of the action to `IBuildLinks`. `IsAssignableFrom` should work irrespective of whether the interface is implemented by the a superclass or the derived class.